# Creating chart component with ApexCharts VUEJS

Tags: vuejs3, apexcharts

I would like some help to create a chart component with APEXCHARTS, I tried here in several ways to create a component so that I can use it anywhere else, just passing the data to populate it, but I couldn't, how can I do it?

I was wanting this chart
[https://apexcharts.com/vue-chart-demos/bar-charts/stacked/](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

i tried to do it this way

```
<template>
  <div class="example">
    <apexchart
      width="800"
      height="500"
      type="bar"
      :options="chartOptions"
      :series="series"
    ></apexchart>

  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
/* eslint-disable */
import { computed} from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
  width: {
    type: [Number, String],
    default: "auto",
  },
  height: {
    type: [Number, String],
    default: "auto",
  }
});


const data = computed(() => {
  return {      
          series: [{
            name: 'Marine Sprite',
            data: [44, 55, 41, 37, 22, 43, 21]
          }, {
            name: 'Striking Calf',
            data: [53, 32, 33, 52, 13, 43, 32]
          }, {
            name: 'Tank Picture',
            data: [12, 17, 11, 9, 15, 11, 20]
          }, {
            name: 'Bucket Slope',
            data: [9, 7, 5, 8, 6, 9, 4]
          }, {
            name: 'Reborn Kid',
            data: [25, 12, 19, 32, 25, 24, 10]
          }],
          chartOptions: {
            chart: {
              type: 'bar',
              height: 350,
              stacked: true,
            },
            plotOptions: {
              bar: {
                horizontal: true,
                dataLabels: {
                  total: {
                    enabled: true,
                    offsetX: 0,
                    style: {
                      fontSize: '13px',
                      fontWeight: 900
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
            },
            stroke: {
              width: 1,
              colors: ['#fff']
            },
            title: {
              text: 'Fiction Books Sales'
            },
            xaxis: {
              categories: [2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014],
              labels: {
                formatter: function (val) {
                  return val + "K"
                }
              }
            },
            yaxis: {
              title: {
                text: undefined
              },
            },
            tooltip: {
              y: {
                formatter: function (val) {
                  return val + "K"
                }
              }
            },
            fill: {
              opacity: 1
            },
            legend: {
              position: 'top',
              horizontalAlign: 'left',
              offsetX: 40
            }
          },          
    };
});

</script>
```

```
<template>
<StackedBarChart />
</template>

<script setup>
import StackedBarChart from "@/components/apex-charts/StackedBarChart.vue";
.....
</script>
```

but when I call it it gives errors

> apexcharts.common.js:6 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')
> at t2.value (apexcharts.common.js:6:80897)
> at t2.value (apexcharts.common.js:6:88989)
> at new t2 (apexcharts.common.js:14:21270)
> at init (vue3-apexcharts.common.js:353:21)

Comment: Hi, Have you tried to remove `type` attribute from the `<apexchart>` component?

Comment: true, I took it, but then I got this error

vue3-apexcharts.common.js:337 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'chart')
     at init (vue3-apexcharts.common.js:337:45)

Comment: You are using Composition API of Vue and in that you used `computed` property of `data` and `chartOptions` can be accessible using `data.chartOptions` as you used a data object as computed property. Else you have to print `chartOptions` or `data` and need to check it.

Comment: ok, got it, but how can I turn it into a component to reuse in several places?

Comment: You can just import it any other component and pass the props fields as properties and it will work.

Comment: I understood and managed to do it here